# Как изменить дату создания папки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как изменить дату создания папки с помощью Python'а?

Comment: http://python.su/forum/topic/5110/

Comment: Меняется дата изменения, но не дата создания.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996405/how-do-i-change-the-file-creation-date-of-a-windows-file-from-python передавайте кортеж (время создания, время создания)

Comment: @ZaArs Меняется дата файла, но не дата папки.

Comment: @djimbosfan _"Whether a directory can be given for path depends on whether the operating system implements directories as files (for example, Windows does not)" Вольный перевод_: "Можно ли указать каталог для пути зависит от того, реализует ли операционная система каталоги в виде файлов (например, Windows не делает)" Может, это Ваш случай?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Возможно. Можно ссылку на статью?

Comment: @djimbosfan Это цитата из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime). 4 абзац.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124404/changing-directory-create-times-ctime-using-python-in-windows)

Comment: @MaxU Увы у меня это не сработало...

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя изменить такое. Это все равно что поменять дату рождения человека. Однако можно так (это будет долго для больших папок):

```
import shutil

folder_name = 'example_folder' #название папки, которую нужно пересоздать
folder_path = r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\example_folder' 
new_folder_path = r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\new_folder' 

if os.path.exists(folder_path):
    shutil.rmtree(folder_path) 
    os.mkdir(new_folder_path) 

    #копируем файлы
    for file_name in os.listdir(new_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(new_folder_path, file_name)
        new_file_path = os.path.join(new_folder_path, file_name)
        shutil.copyfile(file_path, new_file_path)
else:
    print("не найдены")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]